# Calculating length of clipped lines using buffered points using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, error-000732, error-000800

I need to create a buffer around each point of a points feature class. I would then want to use the point buffers to clip the streets feature class to calculate the length of the clipped streets using ArcPy.

I need some guidance in summarizing the length of the streets regarding their types.

The "summarizing" in the following script does not work, I receive the following message:

```
ERROR 000732: Input Table: Dataset roads_0 does not exist or is not supported
ERROR 000800: The value is not a member of SUM | MEAN | MIN | MAX | RANGE | STD |   COUNT | FIRST | LAST.
Failed to execute (Statistics).
```

My ArcPy script so far:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = "D:/Data/ToYahya"

# Perform the buffer which will create one circular buffer per site
arcpy.Buffer_analysis("test_point.shp", "Buffer_test.shp", "50 Meters", "FULL",   "ROUND", "NONE", "")

# Open a search cursor and use the geometry of each buffer polygon in turn to Clip roads
# Use the id of each buffer polygon as suffix on the out road shapefile
features = arcpy.SearchCursor("Buffer_test.shp")
for feature in features:
      bufferPoly = feature.SHAPE
      arcpy.Clip_analysis("road.shp", bufferPoly, "road_" + str(feature.FID))

      arcpy.Statistics_analysis("road_" + str(feature.FID), "outStatsTable", "Shape_Leng", "type")
del feature,features
```

Comment: Where are you stuck? Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: Your indentation after the `for` line looks wrong - can you check that and then run the script again and just report the first error you see.  The two errors posted look like they come from separate runs.

Comment: i checked the code, everything is correct but i got the same error mentioned above...... i do not know where is the error

Comment: thank you everybody for help actually i found the solution where i changed the clip and statistic code like following:     arcpy.Clip_analysis("road.shp", bufferPoly, "road_" + str(feature.FID)+".shp")
    
    arcpy.Statistics_analysis("road_" + str(feature.FID)+".shp","outStatsTable_"+ str(feature.FID), [["Shape_Leng", "SUM"]], "type")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work - just run each tool interactively to work out the parameter values, then [Copy As Python Snippet](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002t00000011000000) each result from the Geoprocessing | Results window into a Python script and your done:

1. [Buffer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//000800000019000000)
2. [Clip](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Clip/000800000004000000/)
3. [Summary Statistics](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000001z000000)

I've modified your code quite a lot below.  It is untested but should work as long as your sites.shp has a field called "id" with unique values.  I will leave you to incorporate the Summary Statistics part because I do not know where/if you are already storing lengths in the roads.shp.

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = "D:/Data/ToYahya"

# Perform the buffer which will create one circular buffer per site
arcpy.Buffer_analysis("Sites.shp", "Buffer.shp", "400 Meters", "FULL", "ROUND", "NONE", "")

# Open a search cursor and use the geometry of each buffer polygon in turn to Clip roads
# Use the id of each buffer polygon as suffix on the out road shapefile
features = arcpy.SearchCursor("Buffer.shp")
for feature in features:
    bufferPoly = feature.SHAPE
    arcpy.Clip_analysis("road.shp", bufferPoly, "road_" + str(feature.id))
del feature,features
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, i have applied the processing you mentioned but the results does not fit my requirements where i got one bufer layer and one clip layer, but i need to generate one buffer layer around each point and one clip layer for each buffer. so please can you help me.....

Comment: You can use arcpy.SearchCursor to get the geometry of each buffer and then use that to Clip the lines and perform Summary Statistics multiple times.

Comment: that's what i am searching for (SearchCursor) but i could not write the correct code, so please can you send me how to wirte the code. thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post your code so far into your question, please?  I always prefer to see how far someone has progressed before helping with where they are stuck.

Comment: I added the code to my question.....

Comment: It's late here now but if no one else looks at it over night, I will try to in the morning.

Comment: I am very thankful for your help. actually it works perfectly with a small edit "str(feature.id)"

Comment: That's fixed now :-)

Comment: Hi, please today i try to make summarize to the length of the road according the type of the road but it does not work....i used this code: Statistics_analysis (in_table, out_table, statistics_fields, {case_field})..... so please do you have any suggestion?

Comment: This sounds like a new question - rather than trying to deal with it as a continuation can you perhaps accept the answer that you said "works perfectly" and then start a new question using your current code to show where it goes astray and how?

Comment: ok, thanks.. i have edited the code in the question but this one does not work.

Comment: When you say "does not work" it tells us little - can you please edit your question not only to include the code but also to tell us what is different in the result from what you expect?  Or if it gives an error message edit the question to include that.

Comment: actually i got a message says: "road_" + str(feature.FID) is not defined..... that all, so the first part until statistics is working but then the error.

Comment: Can you edit your question to say that, please?  While editing make sure your Python script indentation matches my example, and check whether your Buffer_test.shp has a field called FID.